# Relacionamento no doctrine

Tags: php, mvc, orm, doctrine, symfony-2

Estou com um problema que é análoga a seguinte situação:

Uma carro pode ter ou não um motorista, ou seja um carro pode ter no minimo 0 e no máximo 1 motorista.

Uma motorista pode ou não tem um carro, ou seja uma motorista pode ter no minimo 0 e no máximo 1 carro.

> No exemplo em questão estamos aceitando que o motorista pode ter no
>   máximo um carro.

Transformando isso em classe teríamos então duas classes.

```
<?php 
class Carro{
    /**
    * esse deve aceitar null
    */
    private $motorista;
}


class Motorista{
    /**
    * esse deve aceitar null
    */
    private $carro;
}
```

Ao meu ver o mapeamento que mais me interessaria seria OneToOne, mas não sei se deveria ser OneToMany ou ManyToOne, se fosse possível fazer com que ele aceitasse valores null, contudo, gostaria de saber qual é a melhor forma para fazer usando o doctrine e a forma mais correta segundo Designer Partner (pergunto pois pode ser que a melhor forma de fazer usando o doctrine não seja a forma mais correta).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra mim, a classe `Carro` teria um atributo `$motorista`, assim como a classe `Motorista` teria o atributo `$carro` (resultando em um relacionamento um-para-um, bidirecional). Ambos os atributos seriam `nullable`.

Assim você ficaria com uma tabela Carro e uma tabela Motorista, sendo que a tabela Motorista possui uma coluna referenciando Carro.

Note que essa restrição ficaria apenas no nível da sua aplicação – se alguém quisesse inserir os dados diretamente no banco, passando por cima da restrição, poderia.

```
<?php

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Carro
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Motorista", mappedBy="carro")
     * @JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $motorista;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Motorista
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Carro", inversedBy="motorista")
     * @JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $carro;
}
```